# Twitter OAuth 500 internal server error

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

This simple code doesnt work... can anyone help me find the problem... it gives me 500 internal server error

```
include "../twitter-async/EpiCurl.php";
include "../twitter-async/EpiOAuth.php";
include "../twitter-async/EpiTwitter.php";
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY","my_key");
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET","my_secret");
function init($oauth_token = null, $oauth_token_secret = null)
{
        return new EpiTwitter(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,$oauth_token,$oauth_token_secret);
}

$twitter = init();

if($twitter)
{
    echo "success";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, there's a typo in your init function(TWITTER_CONSUER_SECRET vs TWITTER_CONSU **M** ER_SECRET), but I don't think that will cause a 500 error.

Comment: yup I did that still doesnt work

Comment: Create a file that has the contents `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and put it in the same place as the file you are receiving the 500 error on. If you still receive a 500 error when you hit that file, you'll know that something is wrong with the server config and not necessarily with this code.

Comment: nope server is fine but I cannot find curl multi init in phpinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there an error control in EpiTwitter class?

try this:

```
<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", "1");
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  echo (init()) ? "success" : "error";
?>
```